# ActiveRecord query optimization

Tags: mysql, activerecord, query-optimization

I have an ActiveRecord query that is sometimes taking up to a minute to complete. I'm trying to find ways to optimize it but unsure where to start with it.

I have the following code:

```
average_sql = 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, LEAST(notification_sent, responded_at), responded_at)'
UserPlacement.notified.responded.joins(:placement_campaign)
                     .merge(PlacementCampaign.not_instant)
                     .where('user_placements.created_at > ?', 3.months.ago).select(average_sql)
```

which translates to:

```
SELECT Timestampdiff(minute, Least(notification_sent, responded_at),
       responded_at)
FROM   `user_placements`
       INNER JOIN `placement_campaigns`
               ON `placement_campaigns`.`id` =
                  `user_placements`.`placement_campaign_id`
                  AND `placement_campaigns`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
WHERE  `user_placements`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       AND ( `user_placements`.`notification_sent` IS NOT NULL )
       AND ( `user_placements`.`responded_at` IS NOT NULL )
       AND `placement_campaigns`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       AND `placement_campaigns`.`instant` = 0
       AND ( user_placements.created_at > {{ 3.months.ago }} )
       AND `user_placements`.`user_id` = 1
```

the `user_placements` table indexes:

```
index_user_p_campaign_unique, ["placement_campaign_id", "user_id"]
fk__user_placements_tuser_id, ["user_id"]
```

and the `placement_campaigns` indexes:

```
index_placement_campaigns_on_placement_id, ["placement_id"]
```

What steps should I go through to analyze and increase performance of this query?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes:

```
placement_campaigns:  INDEX(deleted_at, instant, id)
user_placements:  INDEX(user_id, deleted_at, created_at)
user_placements:  INDEX(placement_campaign_id, user_id,
                        deleted_at, created_at)
```

JOINs are a bit tricky because it is hard to predict which table the Optimizer will pick as the 'first'.

Here is my [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

"3 months ago" can be spelled out as

```
NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```